# -n parameter in sed prevents substitution

Tags: bash, unix, sed

Let's say we want to replace the letter "a" with its Morse code equivalent from a text.txt file to a hidden .out.txt file using sed, with the contents of the original file being "this is a test".

```
#!/bin/bash
touch .out.txt
cat text.txt > .out.txt
sed 's/a/.-/g' .out.txt
```

The output, as expected, is "this is .- test".
However, let's say we want to do multiple instances of sed, without constantly printing the result of each instance of sed using the -n parameter. In this case:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch .out.txt
cat text.txt > .out.txt
sed -n 's/a/.-/g' .out.txt
sed -n 's/t/-/g' .out.txt
cat .out.txt
```

However, in this case, the output of cat is the same as the contents of text.txt, "this is a test".
Is there a possible substitute for `-n`, or in general a way to prevent sed from printing anything with our wanted result?

Comment: `sed -n 's/t/-/g' .out.txt` is not really changing `out.txt` at all.

Comment: To emphasize what @anubhava said: `sed` does not, by default, *modify* the files referenced on the command line.  It simply sends the modified output to *stdout*.  *Nothing* you are doing ever makes changes to your `.out.txt` file.

Comment: In addition, the `-n` suppresses the automatic output.   You then have to tell sed what to output (using a `p` at the end of the expression).   `sed -in 's/a/.-/pg' .out.txt`...   Note: this will not print non-matching lines.

Comment: Is there any reason why wouldn't go with `sed -e 's/a/.-/g' -e 's/t/-/g' test.txt > .out.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your seds `sed --help` for the syntax of `-i`option.
This is necessary, because the syntax is different depending on which sed you are using, i.e. I cannot simply tell you.
Then use it accordingly to have the effects of sed take place **i**n-place on the file.